# Active Directory In MS dynamic CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to add a  field on Lead Form that will contain a dropdown list/Lookup of my account's Active directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everyone is active directory is also a CRM user, then add a lookup on the lead form to the user entity.

Comment: i've tried it, but i want this for all users weather its a CRM user Or Non-Crm user.